# Solr is stopped when update/reindex

Tags: solr

Production server : Solr 5.4.1, Ruby on rails, Ubuntu server.

Solr is suddenly stopped, when I restarted, it work to select/get data but for any update/reindex record job execute, again Solr is stopped. In log also I can not find any error statement.

I have compared the solr log for running system and stopped system and found that after runing `DirectUpdateHander2 end_commit_flush`, below log does not exist on non-working system log:

> 97588877 INFO  (searcherExecutor-7-thread-1-processing-x:namecol) [x:namecol] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [namecol] Registered new searcher Searcher@1bf35cb6[namecol main{ExitableDirectoryReader(UninvertingDirectoryReader(Uninverting(_3rc22(5.4.1):C68771/19227:delGen=227) Uninverting(_4ee4k(5.4.1):C43777/12974) Uninverting(_4fogn(5.4.1):C13374/2400) Uninverting(_4fopo(5.4.1):c1712/83) Uninverting(_4fomr(5.4.1):c1150/216) Uninverting(_4foqs(5.4.1):c995/64) Uninverting(_4for4(5.4.1):c156) Uninverting(_4for8(5.4.1):c94) Uninverting(_4for9(5.4.1):c3)))}

Which part do I need to check? I have set `softCommit` to -1 so now solr is not stopped after any frontend changes but also not update the select data also until not restart it again.

Comment: If the Solr log doesn't way anything, your process is probably being killed by the OS because the server is out of memory. `/var/log/syslog` will usually have a message about the OOM killer doing its thing and removing the process in that case.

Comment: i can not find error log in syslog  i have retrace the solr log and find two error:  PERFORMANCE WARNING: Overlapping onDeckSearchers=2
SolrIndexSearcher has not changed - not re-opening    , is there any way to solve it using any config setting? for now no update happen in the project but when restart solr then past pending update display. I thin new server is not open after end commit flush

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I have created a new core and re-index all data again.

And also updated the Solr version to 8.8.2 for the better stable release.